# Regex - match last CSS selector in a list

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

Here is my regex: https://regex101.com/r/UWx4mt/3/

I need to select the last expression in a list and apply the replace rule.

I think it is evident what I am trying to do in the example above, nonetheless: I am trying to duplicate CSS selectors replace #test-id dynamically with #content, so they apply to the new div.

Any help is appreciated, I think I am very close! 
Thanks.

**Edit:** Running the regex a second time with `(#test-id)([^,|^{]+){` gives me the desired result. I wonder whether there is a way to do it all-in-one.

**Edit 2:** Desired output:

```
#test-id .pagination-next,
#content .pagination-next, 
#test-id .pagination-previous,
#content .pagination-previous, 
#content .tabs, 
#test-id .tabs {
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none
}
```

(see the #content .tabs, line is not added in the regex above, it is only added by the regex in Edit1)

Comment: Can you share the desired output?

Comment: Sure! Added it to the post, does that help?

Comment: I think the easiest solution here is to use two regexes.